# Custom checkbox styling not working in FF and Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created my own custom checkbox styles which are working in Chrome. But they are not working in Edge or Firefox. What's going wrong?

```css
h5.roi-h5 {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #999999;
  padding: 10px !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.roi .roidivider {
  height: 30px;
  border-top: solid 1px #999999;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.roi .roilocations {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.roi-label {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 11px;
  color: #999999;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.roi label {
  color: #999999;
}

.roi .form-group {
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
}

.roi .roiinfobox {
  clear: both;
}

.roi input[type='number'] {
  text-align: center;
  color: #db291d;
}

.roi .summary {
  display: none;
}

input.roisavings {
  height: 200px;
  border: 0px !important;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: #5f96aa;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.roi .roifirstname input,
.roi .roilastname input,
.roi .roicompany input,
.roi .roiemail input {
  border: 0px !important;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.roi ::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #666F8F;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

.roi :-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: #666F8F;
}

.roi ::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: #666F8F;
}

.roi .form-control {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

.roi input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

.roi input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  content: "+";
}

.roi input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  background: url(https://svgshare.com/i/DMS.svg) no-repeat center center;
  content: '';
  left: 5px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: .2s opacity;
  -o-transition: .2s opacity;
  transition: .2s opacity;
}

.roi input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.roi label[title]:after,

/* for Episerver < v8 */

.roi label[title]:after {
  /* For Episerver v8+ */
  background-color: #C9C9C9;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ACACAC;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: "?";
  /* make this whatever you want */
  cursor: help;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 14px;
}

.roi label[title=""]:after,
.roi label[title=""]:after {
  display: none;
}

.roi label[title]:hover:after,
.roi label[title]:hover:after {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
}

.roi div label input {
  /*margin-right: 100px;*/
}

.roi #ck-button {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  overflow: auto;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.roi #ck-button input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.roi #ck-button label {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.col-sm-4.text-center.center-block {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.roi #ck-button label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  color: #db291d;
}

.roi #ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

.roi #ck-button input:checked+span {
  background-color: #db291d;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="roi">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label title="test 1" class="control-label col-sm-10 roi-label">I am the caption 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="checkbox" roiname="roiinput" name="locations" value="1" class="roicheckox form-control FormChoice__Input FormChoice__Input--Checkbox" checked data-f-datainput />
    </div>

    <label title="test 2" class="control-label col-sm-10 roi-label">I am the caption 2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="checkbox" roiname="roiinput" name="locations" value="2" class="roicheckox form-control FormChoice__Input FormChoice__Input--Checkbox" unchecked data-f-datainput />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/partisanentity/w1k9xec4/12/) to see it all in action.

Comment: What specific goes wrong in Edge/Firefox?

Comment: Seems to work in my Firefox (ver 67 on MacOS 10.13.6). I see a big red checkmark in a square box with a thin grey border.

Comment: If I run the jsfiddle link in FF for example I only see very small boxes for the checkboxes and the tick mark is black instead of red.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: Applying a pseudo-element to an <input> is likely to not work in some browsers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field/4660434#4660434